# Yahoo Messenger API - parameter_absent: oauth_signature

Tags: oauth, yahoo

I'm just not able to solve this for days now, anyone have any ideas? Below is the request response as shown by Fiddler
The response is that the oauth_signature is absent, however it was sent. If I calculated the signature incorrectly i would expect signature_invalid
I feel like the issue is staring me in the face, but I can't see it.

```
GET      http://developer.messenger.yahooapis.com    /v1/session HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth
realm: "yahooapis.com"
oauth_version: "1.0"
oauth_token: "The oauth token "
oauth_nonce: "4724376"
oauth_timestamp: "1449488987"
oauth_consumer_key: "My consumer key"
oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1"
oauth_signature: "oBjiENcrXBX6I5dE/Vr7AHj2FOA="
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Host: developer.messenger.yahooapis.com

HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2015 11:49:34 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem="parameter_absent:      oauth_signature", realm="yahooapis.com"
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Cache-Control: private

17b
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

Please provide valid credentials.  OAuth oauth_problem="parameter_absent:     oauth_signature", realm="yahooapis.com"
```

Many thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:
I was creating a new request header for each authentication item. All the OAuth tokens must go in the same header. ie. the Authorization header

The code below is how I add create the Authorization header, which works fine now.

```
string OAuthHeader = "OAuth realm=\"yahooapis.com\"," +
            "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumerkey + "\"," +
            "oauth_timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\"," +
            "oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\"," +
            "oauth_version=\"1.0\"," +
            "oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\"," +
            "oauth_token=\"" + dictGetRequestTokenParams["oauth_token"] + "\"," +
            "oauth_signature=\"" + consumerSecret + "%26" + dictGetRequestTokenParams["oauth_token_secret"] + "\",";

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, OAuthHeader);
```